# How to fix blurry imageView in Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, imageview, adt

I have an activity, which only has an image. Which is way too blurry. How do I fix its blur and get it back sharp? I have not added any special things to it. And I actually want the image to cover at least half the screen. It is just the image which has become blurred and I can't figure out how to fix it since 5 hours.

My SorryAnim.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0C090A"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.dhairyadev.sorry.SorryAnim" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scale="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/pls" />
```

My SorryAnim.java:

```
package com.dhairyadev.sorry;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SorryAnim extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sorry_anim);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sorry_anim, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.about_dev:
        Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), AboutDev.class);
        startActivity (intent);
    }
    return false;
}



}
```

Looking for helpful answer ASAP. :)

Comment: I don't see code where you're using the activity.xml resource.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get you?

Comment: R.layout.<id> where id is the name of the xml file. The code you posted doesn't use R.layout.activity.

Comment: Um yes. Does that relate to my image being blurred?

Comment: Yes. You may have written code that blurs out the image from R.layout.activity. But because you're not showing that code, I can't see what you did.

Comment: So which more code shall I show?

Comment: It looks like you've edited your post so that the xml file matches the code. So you don't need to show anything else. I can only answer questions based on the information present. If you post misleading information, then either my answer will be correct, but invalid for you because it is based on incorrect information, or I'd be unable to answer the question - because there is inconsistent information present.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that may make it blure is that you are stretching it to `match_parent`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Or the image is assets is just blurred.

Try to remove the scaling and see if it is changing anything.

Comment: No use. You're saying me to remove layout_width, layout_height, right? It doesn't work.

Comment: @Dhairyadev don't remove it, change it to wrap_content

Comment: I did that. Then it becomes way too small.

Comment: @Dhairyadev well here is your answer, you can't scale small picture and expect it to not be blurry, it always will. Find a bigger image.

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageView height and width are set to match_parent. Unless your drawable happens to be exactly the size of the screen, it will be stretched, i.e. interpolated. Try changing height and width to wrap_content to see the image in it's original form.

Comment: I changed it to wrap_content. But then it becomes way too small.

Comment: Exactly that's your problem. If you want a high res image, you have to make one. You can't interpolate a high res image out of a low res one.

Comment: So the fault is in the image?

Comment: It's not a fault. The image has a certain size. It's a small image. If you want to display it on more pixels, the extra pixels have to be interpolated, that makes it look blurred.

Comment: I captured it from a Nexus 7 2013. It's quite big. Idk how it becomes that small. :/

Comment: It's a screenshot? Should be plenty big. Have you edited it in some way? Check the dimension of the image on your PC.

Comment: no. I just copied it to my PC. Please check the process how I add the image : on Activity.xml, drag imageView to the screen ->Create new icon... -> add name -> choose file -> done. And then it comes in 4 sizes in drawable-hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi. Correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that process, but it sounds like you're creating an icon, which are usually small images. If you just want to use the original image unchanged, you can just copy it (the original) into the drawable-nodpi folder (create this if it doesn't exist), and remove the "icons" you have created.